# MVC Website to be Developed to Run on a Windows Mobile 6.5 Handheld Device?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to develop a web application to run on a `win 6.5 handheld` for scanning and shop floor data capture purposes.

I plan to use MVC 5 but my question is :

- How to get started in visual studio (2013?). For a windows app I would target the device/operating system but uncertain for browser based apps.
- Do I need a specific SDK or type of visual studio project? Or do I just develop as if writing a website that would run on a desktop - could I encounter issues regarding limited device processing power or touch gestures.

Comment: What is your plan to "scan" using a webbrowser on 6.5?

Comment: The device scanner will populate a form field. Much like scanning to word pad or notes etc. If needed we can include a postamble line break and submit the page on enter.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a browser agnostic framework, and as such you dont have to target any specific browser when you setup the project.

What I would be aware of though is all the newer css styling and some jquery / javascript libraries will not be compatable and you will have to code around these shortfalls in the browser

Hope this helps

link to similar question

http://forums.asp.net/t/1685674.aspx?MVC+good+for+windows+Mobile+6+5+mobile+application

Comment: Thanks Martyn. I'm more concerned with code limitations than browser compliance. I guess my question should be is there any .NET code that should be avoided for browser based apps on a mobile pc, and if so is there a mobile MVC project that helps with this? Thanks again.

Comment: You still seem to be confused with `MVC is a browser agnostic framework`.  This means that MVC by default has not idea what is connecting to it, it could be an Apple IIe, and it still does what it does.  The reason it doesn't matter is that all .Net code runs on the server.  You can do anything you want on the server and the client doesn't care, it doesn't know, it really doesn't matter what-so-ever.

Comment: @radiator as Erik says, It does not matter what .NET code you use, I may have confused you in regards to my comment `code around these shortfalls in the browser` what I mean by that is some jquery plugins may not work and you will have to use vanilla javascript instead as the library may not be supported. it would seem win mobile runs a version of IE6 so try to do css / javascript to ie6